# Search a keyword in all the answers to my own questions

Tags: support, search

weeks ago, I read a good answer to my question,

I only remember there's a key word python3.8 in the answer.

How could I search the `python3.8` through all the answers I got.

Comment: No direct way to do that using the built in search, must use tools like SEDE for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/924192/search-in-answers-to-a-users-questions?UserId=10569317&Query=%25python%25), but I wasn't able to find the answer you were thinking about (at least not on Stack Overflow).

You can change the query parameters to explore further; on the bottom, there's a site switcher. Your `UserId` (which is site-specific) is in the URL of your profile page. Note that the query is **case sensitive**.

[image]